# Xamarin.Froms Error: Models.User can not be converted to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am building a cross platform app with Xamarin and MVVM model. I have done many research on my current issue, but didn't come across an answer/clue that will help me in the forums. So, I decided to share it and hoping to get a help. I have a back end server where I can do API calls thru access token. In my back end, I have created an account table that has firstname, lastname, email etc. rows. I have created an user view model in mobile app where I can display authenticated user info. When I debug I can see that I successfully get user info however, I cannot bind the result into my view, get this error: Models.User can not be converted to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. I cannot figure it out what it is. Any help would be much appreciated.

This is my ApiService code where I do API calls to back end server and get user info with an access token:

```
public async Task<User> GetUsersAsync(string accessToken)
{
  var client = new HttpClient();
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
  "Bearer", accessToken);

  var json = await client.GetStringAsync(Constants.BaseApiAddress + "api/Account/UserInfo");

  var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);

  return user;
}
```

This is my UserViewModel where sets the api call for the specific user based on access Token

```
public class UserViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private readonly ApiServices _apiServices = new ApiServices();
  private User _users;

  public User Users
  {
    get => _users;
    set
    {
      _users = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public ICommand GetUserCommand
  {
    get
    {
      return new Command(async () =>
      {
        var accessToken = Settings.AccessToken;
        Users = await _apiServices.GetUsersAsync(accessToken);
        });
      }
    }
}
```

This is my user model

```
public class User
{
  [JsonProperty("FirstName")]
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty("LastName")]
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty("Children")]
  public string Children { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty("Email")]
  public string Email { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty("Image")]
  public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

This is my UserProfile view XAML

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewModels:UserViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<StackLayout Padding="20">


    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"
              HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Padding="0,10">
                        <Label Style="{StaticResource ProfileNameLabel}" Text="{Binding Email}" />
                        <Label Margin="0,-5" Style="{StaticResource ProfileTagLabel}" Text="{Binding FirstName}" />

                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

UserProfile view code behind

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class UserProfilePage : ContentPage
{
  UserViewModel usersViewModel;

  public UserProfilePage ()
  {
    InitializeComponent ();
    BindingContext = usersViewModel = new UserViewModel();
  }

  protected override void OnAppearing()
  {
    base.OnAppearing();

    usersViewModel.GetUserCommand.Execute(null);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ListView is for displaying a List of multiple items, and its ItemSource must be an `IEnumerable` (ie, a **Collection** of objects).  Your Users object is just a single item. You could make `Users` a `List<User>` containing just a single item

```
public List<User> Users
```

or you could use a different UI element for displaying your data

Comment: Just adding that a `ObservableCollection<User>` will make your life simpler if you pretend to add and remove users

Comment: Retrieving it as a list lead me to following error: 

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[App.Models.User]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: your data is NOT a list/array!  That's the problem.  You need to create a List and insert your single item of data into it.  This should not require any change to your deserialization.

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense now. Thank you Jason!